# Catching QSpinBox text field mouseEvents

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent

I have a reimplemented QDoubleSpinBox.  I would like to catch `mouseDoubleClickEvent` to enable the user to change `singleStep` by way of `QInputDialog::getDouble()`.

My problem is that when I reimplement the `mouseDoubleClickEvent` I only catch double clicks that occur over the arrow buttons.  I actually want to ignore double clicks that occur in the arrows and only catch double clicks that occur in the text field.  I have a feeling that I need to reimplement the mouseDoubleClickEvent of a child of the QDoubleSpinBox, but I'm not sure how to reimplement a child event nor how to select the correct child See my attempt at limiting to a child QRect in code: I think I need to specify which child...?

Thanks.

Edit: corrected class declaration/definition name mismatch.

MyQDoubleSpinBox.h

```
class MyQDoubleSpinBox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyQDoubleSpinBox(QString str, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyQDoubleSpinBox();

public slots:
    void setStepSize(double step);

private:
    double stepSize;
    QString name;

protected:
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
};
```

MyQDoubleSpinBox.cpp

```
#include "MyQDoubleSpinBox.h"

MyQDoubleSpinBox::MyQDoubleSpinBox(QString str, QWidget *parent)
    :   QDoubleSpinBox(parent), stepSize(1.00), name(str)
{
    this->setMinimumWidth(150);
    this->setSingleStep(stepSize);
    this->setMinimum(0.0);
    this->setMaximum(100.0);
}

MyQDoubleSpinBox::~MyQDoubleSpinBox()
{

}

void MyQDoubleSpinBox::setStepSize(double step)
{
    this->setSingleStep(step);
}

void MyQDoubleSpinBox::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if( this->childrenRect().contains(e->pos()) )
    {
        bool ok;
        double d = QInputDialog::getDouble(this,
            name,
            tr("Step Size:"),
            this->singleStep(),
            0.0,
            1000.0,
            2,
            &ok);

        if(ok)
            this->setSingleStep(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of the hack getting ref to child, but it works =)

MyQDoubleSpinBox.h:

```
class MyQDoubleSpinBox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyQDoubleSpinBox(QString str, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyQDoubleSpinBox();

public slots:
    void setStepSize(double step);

private:
    double stepSize;
    QString name;

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *e);
};
```

MyQDoubleSpinBox.cpp

```
MyQDoubleSpinBox::MyQDoubleSpinBox(QString str, QWidget *parent)
    :   QDoubleSpinBox(parent), stepSize(1.00), name(str)
{
    this->setMinimumWidth(150);
    this->setSingleStep(stepSize);
    this->setMinimum(0.0);
    this->setMaximum(100.0);
    QLineEdit *editor = this->findChild<QLineEdit *>("qt_spinbox_lineedit");
    editor->installEventFilter(this);
}

MyQDoubleSpinBox::~MyQDoubleSpinBox()
{

}

void MyQDoubleSpinBox::setStepSize(double step)
{
    this->setSingleStep(step);
}

bool MyQDoubleSpinBox::eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QMouseEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)
    {        bool ok;
        double d = QInputDialog::getDouble(this,
                                           name,
                                           tr("Step Size:"),
                                           this->singleStep(),
                                           0.0,
                                           1000.0,
                                           2,
                                           &ok);

        if(ok)
            this->setSingleStep(d);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Instead of overwriting events, i got ref to underlying *QLineEdit* and assigned event filter to it. In event filter catch only mouse double click.

Answer (score 0):

You have direct access to QLineEdit using this->lineEdit()

```
MyQDoubleSpinBox::MyQDoubleSpinBox(QString str, QWidget *parent)
    :   QDoubleSpinBox(parent), stepSize(1.00), name(str)
{
    this->setMinimumWidth(150);
    this->setSingleStep(stepSize);
    this->setMinimum(0.0);
    this->setMaximum(100.0);
    QLineEdit *editor = this->lineEdit(); // change here
    editor->installEventFilter(this);
}
```